# Python3: Correct way of doing ORM using metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, orm

The following source file created ORM `Car` to represent a database table.

But `Car.brand` became `None` afterward. Due to `TableMetaCls` is setting to all the db fields to None. How do I persevered `Car.brand` to `StringField()`? What's the properly way of doing? This is similar to django ORM, please see https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/base.py#L477 for reference.

```
class Field:
    pass


class StringField(Field):
    pass


class TableMetaCls(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        # backup field definition
        field_definitions = {}
        for x, y in attr.items():
            if isinstance(y, Field):
                field_definitions[x] = y
        attr['field_definitions'] = field_definitions

        # set field val to null
        for x, y in attr.items():
            if isinstance(y, Field):
                attr[x] = None

        return super(TableMetaCls, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)


class Table(metaclass=TableMetaCls):
    def save(self):
        pass


class Car(Table):
    brand = StringField()
    model = StringField()


c = Car()
c.brand = "BMW"

print(Car.brand)
```

Comment: what does `print(c.brand)` return?

Comment: It returns None

Comment: `c.brand` and `Car.brand` are None?

Comment: c.brand is "bmw", Car.brand is "None"

Answer (score 1):

It's `None` since you explicitly set all the `Field` attributes to `None` in the metaclass's `__new__`. You could start by doing something like this:

```
class Field:
    pass


class StringField(Field):
    pass


class TableMetaCls(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attr):
        field_definitions = {}
        for name, field in attr.items():
            if isinstance(field, Field):
                field_definitions[name] = field
                field._name = name
        attr["_field_definitions"] = field_definitions
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attr)


class Table(metaclass=TableMetaCls):
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in object.__getattribute__(self, "_field_definitions"):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, "_data").get(name)
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self._field_definitions:
            self._data[name] = value
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)


    def save(self):
        pass


class Car(Table):
    brand = StringField()
    model = StringField()


c = Car()
c2 = Car()

c.brand = "BMW"

print(c.brand)
print(c2.brand)
print(Car.brand)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> BMW
> None
> <__main__.StringField object at 0x10393bc10>
> ```

Comment: Do you need `__getattribute__` under TableMetaCls?

Comment: @user1187968 Good catch, it's not strictly required with this example.